# Two different Assets Pallet instance for pallet_asset_conversion Pallet

Tags: runtime, assets, pallet-asset-tx-payment

While reviewing the substrate runtime code, I noticed that the pallet_asset_conversion Pallet references two distinct instances for the Assets Pallet within its Runtime Config:

```
impl pallet_asset_conversion::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type AssetBalance = <Self as pallet_balances::Config>::Balance;
    type HigherPrecisionBalance = sp_core::U256;
    **type Assets = Assets;**
    type Balance = u128;
    **type PoolAssets = PoolAssets;**
```

Could you clarify the purpose of having two separate instances for the same pallet?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is very simple; using the same pallet multiple times in your runtime, but with a different configuration. Asset Hub is a good example. It uses two instances of `pallet-assets`:

- [instance1](https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/blob/c86afcc9ef185465df30878e4415cf6d8212fcd6/system-parachains/asset-hubs/asset-hub-polkadot/src/lib.rs#L274) is for the native assets (`AssetId: u32`) and e.g. the `CreateOrigin` is `EnsureSigned`. Meaning that everyone can send a native transaction (not XCM) and create an asset.
- [instance2](https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/blob/c86afcc9ef185465df30878e4415cf6d8212fcd6/system-parachains/asset-hubs/asset-hub-polkadot/src/lib.rs#L312) is for foreign assets (`AssetId: MultiLocation`) and e.g. the `CreateOrigin` needs to be a `MultiLocation` of a parachain or its relay chain.

Have a look yourself and you'll find that the configurations are very different.